# Extern declaration on an extern "C" global variable

Tags: c++

In C and C++ if I want to use a global variable in other compilation units I will define the variable like:

```
int g_myVal = 0;
```

This allocates storage for the `int`.

In the header file I then declare the variable:

```
extern int g_myVal;
```

This informs the compiler that said symbol exists in some other compilation unit. It is then up to the linker to resolve the symbol.

However if I want the variable to be available with "C" linkage I must define the variable (allocate storage) like:

```
extern "C" int g_myVal = 0;
```

So how does one then differentiate between allocating storage and just informing the compiler that said symbol exists in another compilation unit?

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration be `extern int g_myVal;` ?

Comment: @jbgs: [Yes.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/511337ec45757243)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the fact that `extern` and `extern "C"` do two different things.

---

### About `extern`

`extern` on its own is a *storage class specifier*:

> `[C++11: 7.1.1/6]:` The `extern` specifier can be applied only to the names of variables and functions. The `extern` specifier cannot be used in the declaration of class members or function parameters. For the linkage of a name declared with an `extern` specifier, see 3.5. *[ Note:* **The `extern` keyword can also be used in *explicit-instantiations* and *linkage-specifications*, but it is not a *storage-class-specifier* in such contexts.** *—end note ]*

---

### About `extern "C"`

As that trailing note alludes to, there is another context in which you may use the `extern` keyword and that is as a *linkage specifier*:

> `[C++11: 7.5/2]:` Linkage (3.5) between C++ and non-C++ code fragments can be achieved using a *linkage-specification*:
>
> *linkage-specification:*
>       `extern` *string-literal* `{` *declaration-seq*<sub>opt</sub> `}`
>       `extern` *string-literal declaration*

C++ likes to re-use keywords.

---

### Declarations vs definitions

Now, by default, a variable marked with a linkage specifier is a *declaration* rather than a *definition*, so in that sense it is as if you had also used the other meaning of `extern`:

> `[C++11: 7.5/7]:` A declaration directly contained in a *linkage-specification* is treated as if it contains the `extern` specifier (7.1.1) for the purpose of determining the linkage of the declared name and whether it is a definition. Such a declaration shall not specify a storage class. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> extern "C" double f();
> static double f(); // error
> extern "C" int i; // declaration
> extern "C" {
>    int i; // definition
> }
> extern "C" static void g(); // error
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

As you can see in the above example, it is still possible to *either* a declaration or a definition when you use a linkage specifier.

Here's another example of that:

```
// Everything in this block has C linkage
extern "C" {

   // Declaration of g_myVal
   extern int g_myVal;

   // Definition of g_myVal2
   int g_myVal2;
}

int main()
{
    g_myVal2 = 5;  // ok
    g_myVal  = 6;  // not okay - linker error, symbol not found
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/523620a6a0599ce2)

---

### When you add an initialiser...

That all being said, the treatment of `g_myVal` as a *declaration* is **overruled** by your use of an initialiser, which forces the statement to be a definition:

> `[C++11: 7/8]:` Syntactic components beyond those found in the general form of declaration are added to a function declaration to make a function-definition. **An object declaration, however, is also a definition unless it contains the `extern` specifier and has no initializer (3.1).** A definition causes the appropriate amount of storage to be reserved and any appropriate initialization (8.5) to be done.

I hope that this clarifies what is going on in your code with these differing meanings of `extern`.

Comment: the `extern` for `g_myVal` is redundant.

Comment: @user2485710: No, it isn't.

Comment: @user2485710: What does another translation unit have to do with it? I provided a live demo, as well as standard quotes, that all say the same thing: the `extern` is absolutely _not_ redundant. It changes the meaning of the declaration in a significant way.

Comment: @user2485710: Oh, did you mean the `g_myVal` in the original code, the one with the initialiser? Yes, it's redundant there because the statement is a definition anyway, _because it has an initialiser_. That is true. But not the other statement, and none in my answer, nor in the example from the standard.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, putting the initializer `= 0` changed the declaration to a definition, which is why storage is allocated here. (The same would have happened even with just plain `extern`.)